# How To Navigate Page Without Showing White Screen REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

i have simple small application written in react and react router v5

How Can I Navigate Page Without The Legacy Way ?

i Mean That i want that when user clicked on a `<Link to={'page'} />`
 Show user a animation then the page navigate without any white screen like **Youtube**

> I Don't Want to Implement this in React Codes if there is an react module to do this

thanks;

Comment: Checkout [react-loadable](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable)

Comment: You can use semantic UI and implement conditional rendering to display loader while the contents are being rendered after fetching data if any instead of showing a blank screen...
https://semantic-ui.com/elements/loader.html

Comment: @leverglowh is deprecated